# Flutter - GestureDetector onTapDown color changing

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I do want to implement in my bottom sheet a gesturedetector, that should change the color of the container when it calls the `onTapDown` and the `onTapCancel` function of the `GestureDetector`. But the function is not changing anything. I've also put the code below inside a `StatefulWidget` so that I am able to call `setState((){})`.

This is my code:

```
bool enabled = false;
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 30.0),                
            ),
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: (enabled
                  ? textColor
                  : Colors.black54
                ),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: (enabled
            ? background
            : Colors.transparent
          )
        ),
      ),
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details){
        setState(() {
          enabled = true;
        });
      },
      onTapCancel: (){
        setState(() {
          enabled = false;
        });
      },
      onTap: (){
        String r_value;
        if(text == sheetText[0]){
          r_value = "delete";
        } else if(text == sheetText[1]){
          r_value = "edit";
        } else if(text == sheetText[2]){
          r_value = "notification";
        } else {
          return;
        }
        Navigator.pop(context, r_value);
      },
    );
```

I hope somebody is able to help me.

Comment: is `enabled` a field in your `State` class?

Comment: It's just a boolean to control if the container is pressed

Comment: is `bool enabled`  a field in your `State` class?

Comment: no, it is not a field in my state class

Comment: so make it a field inside your `State` class

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your fast answer;

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `bool enabled = false;` from your `build` method, because every time you call `setState` it will have the same value.

Change your `enabled` variable to an instance field.

```
    class YourClass ...

    bool enabled = false;

    ..
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: sorry 1 minute late -.-